# How can I delete minutes, seconds and microseconds from a timestamp value using Python?

Tags: python, timestamp

For example, I have 1508265552 which is 10/17/2017 @ 6:39pm. I want to get 1508263200, which is same day but 6:00pm.For example, I have 1508265552 which is 10/17/2017 @ 6:39pm. I want to get 1508263200, which is same day but 6:00pm.

Comment: And what code have you tried to do this with? Have you heard of the `datetime` module?

Comment: This *should* be straightforward with `datetime` formatting choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little cleaner using the `datetime` module.

Something like this with the `time` module:

```
import time

# convert to string with minutes and seconds removed.
x = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00', time.localtime(1508265552))
# convert back to epoch seconds
print(time.mktime(time.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
```

result:

```
1508263200.0
```

Using the `datetime` module:

```
import datetime

# convert to datetime
x = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1508265552)
# convert back to epoch seconds with minutes and seconds removed.
print(x.replace(minute=0, second=0).timestamp())
```

result:

```
1508263200.0
```